# Shared Library files .so x86 would work on ARM?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi, ctype

I have .so files that work well on my Ubuntu 32bit, would I need different version of them to work on my Raspberry Pi? I am loading them using python. If it wont work, What should I go through?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to recompile them from source. x86 and ARM are completely different microprocessor architectures, and programs/libraries compiled for one **will not** work on the other.