# Is the creation of linux shared libraries consistent between linux x86_64 and arm64 architectures?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, fpic

I'm wondering if the way we create shared libraries is the same between these two architectures.

Let's say I have the file fx.c that contains some functions definitions so I would create a shared library like this :

gcc -fPIC -c fx.c -o fx.o

gcc -shared fx.o -o libtest.so

1)Is this way of creating shared libraries the same in x86_64 and arm64 ?

2)Is it true that shared libraries created in this way are shared by different processes and only one copy of it will reside in memory?

Comment: Answer to 2: Yes, that's what makes it "shared".

Comment: @Barmar, what about answer 1 ?

Comment: That's why you shouldn't ask two questions at one time. How do you decide which answer to accept if one person answers Q1 and someone else answers Q2.

Comment: I doubt there's anything architecture-specific about the options to create shared libraries, but I don't know for sure so I didn't post an answer.

Comment: Shared libraries work well if they're *actually* shared, which apart from certain system libraries, is hardly ever the case. Everyone brings their own "shared" version.

Comment: Q1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242436/shared-library-files-so-x86-would-work-on-arm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the command line options are the same between platforms, however as you dive deeper you find e.g. platform-specific relocations in ELF format object files (relocatables), linker script differences and eventually compiler driver options that can affect code generation